# JSON Parser Error after Moving to Its Own Android Class

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a JSONParser that parses to a string pulled from a raw recourse folder.  It worked perfictly fine when it was within an activity.  Since I need to reuse it in other activities, I moved it into its own Class.

I cant figure why or what I have wrong now. Its virtually unchanged...? 
Please take a look at my method to see what you think.  Thnx

Fragment Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.regulatory_list);
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromFile(file);
        callback(jParser);
    }
```

The Parser Class:

```
    public class JSONParser {

    static JSONArray jArray = null;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONArray getJSONFromFile(InputStream file) {

        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                file.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String jsonString = writer.toString();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jArray;
    }

}
```

Error from JSONException to Log:

```
06-08 16:04:21.504: E/JSON Parser(27082): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"title":"Advisory Circulators","label":"AC","date":"2008-03-03","_id":"1","gotoURL":null,"description":"Provides guidance such as methods, procedures, and practices for complying with regulations and requirements."},{"title":"Airworthiness Directives","label":"AD","date":"2012-06-08","_id":"2","gotoURL":"javascript:navClickListener('bodyContent', dns + '\/wiki\/index.php\/Airworthiness_Directive #content');","description":"Legally enforceable rules that apply to aircraft, aircraft engines, propellers, and appliances."},{"title":"Code of Federal Regulations","label":"CFR","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"3","gotoURL":"javascript:navClickListener('bodyContent',  dns + '\/wiki\/index.php\/Main_Page #content');","description":"Official Rulemaking documents of the CFR in Title 14 and have been published in the Federal Register"},{"title":"Parts Manufacturer Approvals","label":"PMA","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"4","gotoURL":null,"description":"Parts Manufacturer Approvals"},{"title":"Special Airworthiness Info Bulletins","label":"SAIB","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"5","gotoURL":null,"description":"Bulletins issued by manufacturers to provide modification or inspection instructions."},{"title":"Special Federal Aviation Regulation","label":"SFAR","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"6","gotoURL":null,"description":"Official Rulemaking documents that have changed the language of the CFR in Title 14 CFR for aviation."},{"title":"Supplemental Type Certificates","label":"STC","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"7","gotoURL":null,"description":"Document issued by the Federal Aviation Administration approving a product (aircraft, engine, or propeller) modification"},{"title":"Technical Standard Orders","label":"TSO","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"8","gotoURL":null,"description":"Minimum performance standards issued by the FAA for specified materials, parts, processes, and appliances used on civil aircraft."},{"title":"Type Certificate Data Sheets","label":"TCDS","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"9","gotoURL":null,"description":"Repository of Make and Model information of aircraft, engine or propeller including airspeed, weight, and thrust limitations, etc."}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Log after edit:

```
06-08 16:44:42.744: E/JSON Parser(27515): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"title":"Advisory Circulators","label":"AC","date":"2008-03-03","_id":"1","gotoURL":null,"description":"Provides guidance such as methods, procedures, and practices for complying with regulations and requirements."},{"title":"Airworthiness Directives","label":"AD","date":"2012-06-08","_id":"2","gotoURL":"javascript:navClickListener('bodyContent', dns + '\/wiki\/index.php\/Airworthiness_Directive #content');","description":"Legally enforceable rules that apply to aircraft, aircraft engines, propellers, and appliances."},{"title":"Code of Federal Regulations","label":"CFR","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"3","gotoURL":"javascript:navClickListener('bodyContent',  dns + '\/wiki\/index.php\/Main_Page #content');","description":"Official Rulemaking documents of the CFR in Title 14 and have been published in the Federal Register"},{"title":"Parts Manufacturer Approvals","label":"PMA","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"4","gotoURL":null,"description":"Parts Manufacturer Approvals"},{"title":"Special Airworthiness Info Bulletins","label":"SAIB","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"5","gotoURL":null,"description":"Bulletins issued by manufacturers to provide modification or inspection instructions."},{"title":"Special Federal Aviation Regulation","label":"SFAR","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"6","gotoURL":null,"description":"Official Rulemaking documents that have changed the language of the CFR in Title 14 CFR for aviation."},{"title":"Supplemental Type Certificates","label":"STC","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"7","gotoURL":null,"description":"Document issued by the Federal Aviation Administration approving a product (aircraft, engine, or propeller) modification"},{"title":"Technical Standard Orders","label":"TSO","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"8","gotoURL":null,"description":"Minimum performance standards issued by the FAA for specified materials, parts, processes, and appliances used on civil aircraft."},{"title":"Type Certificate Data Sheets","label":"TCDS","date":"2012-01-31","_id":"9","gotoURL":null,"description":"Repository of Make and Model information of aircraft, engine or propeller including airspeed, weight, and thrust limitations, etc."}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

The original class that worked:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.regulatory_list);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String jsonString = writer.toString();
        callback(jsonString);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Log it is showing your JSON is an array, i.e. it looks like this:

```
 ["foo":bar]
```

if it was an object it would look like this:

```
 {"foo":bar}
```

The first thing you try and do is this:

```
 new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

but it's an array! So you need to create an array:

```
 new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

You could then get the objects by looping over the array.

Comment: Thnx,  I missed that when I moved it over but I still get the same Exception. See my edit.  Thnx again.

Comment: @Andaero don't change your question. You should mark as answered and go debug. That was the fix. You can't get the same exception because now you aren't creating a JSONObject. You didn't update the log line

Comment: Didnt add the debug cause its exactly the same. See edit - the Q still holds true.  Thnx

Comment: @Andaero your original class passes a String into the `callback()` method now you are passing a JSONArray/JSONObject, what does the callback method do?

Comment: Thnx,  Some how I had a duplicate line in the callback when I cut and pasted it to another class.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception indicates you're trying to load a JSONObject from data that is a JSONArray.

This [page](http://www.json.org/) contains some useful (and concise!) information regarding JSON data format which will help guide you in using the JSON library.